# iOS individual constant identifier

Tags: ios, core-data, aes

I want to create my app with encryption for some properties, that I will save in CoreData
So I want use AES256. What the best solution for `key` ? So I can use some identifier from device, but I want use iCloud, so what individual constant I can use for each user? I don't want to hardcode `key`. But I don't know what identifier (like UUID in iPhone), that will be always constant and similar for one user in iCloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no unique constant identifier for an iDevice that you can use anymore. However, you can just make a new **UUID** once your app is started for the first time, store this in the `NSUserDefaults` and use that **UUID** - it will never change as long as the app is not installed anew (updates will still keep the **UUID** intact).

Create a UUID like this when your app starts for the first time:

```
NSString* knownUUID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myUUID"];
if (!knownUUID)
{
    NSString *uuid = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];
    [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:uuid forKey:@"myUUID"];
    [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // store defaults
}
```

Comment: but I think it is not safe to save my key in userDefaults. It is why I wanted to use some identifier and don't save this key anywhere for more security

Comment: Encrypt the key then before setting it in the user defaults, with some secret you set hardcoded in your app. And no, there is no perfectly safe way to make sure THAT secret cannot be obtained - but you can hide it in your code to make it more difficult to obtain, like transforming it in function before using it. App security is not really secure in the end ...